# tailwind tooltip in react reusable component

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have problem with style in tailwind my reusable tooltip component.

Link for live project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wtqsp7?file=src/App.js
How I can write correct style, to show tooltip above text, without broke layout on website?

At the moment I have effect(1, but I want effect (2)
[image]
https://dsh.re/89168

I wrote bellow class, but not working, why?

```
   {showTooltip && (
        <div
          className="absolute bottom-full left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 bg-gray-800 text-white rounded-md py-1 px-2 opacity-0 pointer-events-none transition-all duration-300 z-50"
        >
          {content}
        </div>
      )}
```

Comment: You need different CSS check it [here](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/tooltips/)

Comment: @Werthis it is also not working.

Comment: You have added `opacity-0` in your className. Is it intentional? If you remove it it's working fine.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to implement this or you is it just for learning? because if this is work I would recommend to use a component from flowbite or whichever library that already has it figured out.

Comment: @RicardoSilva for learning, how I can do that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue as I see the issue is that the className has opacity-0. Which someone actually already pointed in the comments.

If you remove it and put it in your code. It seems to work correctly as you can find [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jwzeee?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FTooltip.js).

```js
//Tooltip.js
import React, { useState, ReactNode } from 'react';

export default function Tooltip({ content, children }) {
  const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <div
        className="flex cursor-pointer items-center"
        onClick={() => setShowTooltip(!showTooltip)}
        onMouseEnter={() => setShowTooltip(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setShowTooltip(false)}
        >
        {children}
      </div>
      {showTooltip && <div className="absolute bottom-full left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 bg-gray-800 text-white rounded-md py-1 px-2 pointer-events-none transition-all duration-300 z-50">{content}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```